# How to know App navigating to HomeActivity or LoginActivity - Appium

Tags: c#, testing, automation, appium

I am testing my mobile app using **`Appium`**. When app starting it directly navigation to `HomeActivity` sometimes(if user already logged in). If user not logged in then opening `LoginActivity`.

So, how can I know which `activity` starting? so that I can execute logout code accordingly.

This code not executing at all because app navigation to `HomeActivity` directly instead of `LoginActivity`.

```
public void DemoTest()
{
    AndroidElement editElement1 = driver.FindElementById("input_name");
    editElement1.Clear();
    editElement1.SendKeys("ak@ct");
    AndroidElement editElement2 = driver.FindElementById("input_password");
    editElement2.Click();
    editElement2.SendKeys("qa");
    driver.HideKeyboard();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait =TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    AndroidElement editElement3 = driver.FindElementById("btnLogin");
    editElement3.Click();
}
```

Comment: does this below answer helpful to you or you need more help @Arvindraja

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to identify the page as being the home page or login page.
If you have access to the mobile app source code, you could give your home page a "homePage" AutomationId and your login page a "loginPage" AutomationId. If that is not possible, ask the developer to add them for you. Use these Id's in your appium code to uniquely identify the page that got loaded.

In your appium code, these are the steps you need to take:

1. Start your app: `driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, cap);`
2. Give the app some time to get loaded.
3. Check what page you are on, e.g. by checking the AutomationId or a other unique value for those pages.

In your test script, you can do it like this:

```
            try
            {
                control = driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("loginPage");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // No login page found, your in the home page.
                // Code for logging out here.
            }
```

As Suban Dhyako already suggested, a page object design pattern is a very good practice. It keeps your code clean and clear to read. You can read more about it [here](https://www.swtestacademy.com/page-object-model-c/).

Comment: You said above, I need to give automationId's in _app source code_. Is it Mobile app code or appium code you are saying.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated my answer. It's possible that the property that needs to be set in the mobile app source code has another name than `AutomationId`. I know it's `AutomationId` in WPF and Xamarin Forms  XAML code. It could be platform dependant.

Comment: It's ok, no issue. Currently I am learning so getting more cunfusion. I am trying it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to test in fresh app, you can add **noReset = false** capability in your DesiredCapabilities.

If you want to check which screen is visible, there must be unique element or id in the homeActivityScreen and LoginActivityScreen. Then you can use **isDisplayed()** function.

If you use **Page Object Model** it will be very easy for you to check which screen is Display.

> I am going to show sample of page object model in java code. Hope you can convert it into C# code

```
public class HomeActivityScreen {
    //you can use accessibility, id or xpath

    @AndroidFindBy(id = " your element id")
    private MobileElement element1;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "element id")
    private MobileElement element2;

    public HomeActivityScreen(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public boolean isScreenDisplayed() {
        try {
            return element1.isDisplayed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly you can add page object model for other screen. Then in your test class you can check which screen is visible like

```
 HomeActivityScreen homeScreen = new HomeActivityScreen(driver);
 LoginActivityScreen loginScreen = new LoginActivityScreen(driver);

 if(homeScreen.isScreenDisplayed){
     //write your code
 }else if(loginScreen.isScreenDisplayed){
     //write logout code
 }else{
   //none of above screen is visible
 }
```

Comment: Hi, For your first line do I need `driver` object to use like `driver.FindElementById("input_name");`. What is `element Id` in your first line code. Is it refers to single control(label, edittext) of total class. If is refers to class(or activity) then what Id should I provide? Shouild I give code(logic) filename as id(activity1.cs) or UI file `Id` (activity1.axml)

Comment: you don't need to use `driver.FindElementById("input_name");` if you are using page object model. You can use `@AndroidFindBy(id = "input_name")` instead.

Comment: the **element id** in above code is the automation id of your element.

Comment: How can get I `automationId`(or give) ? It is given by developer?

Comment: Suppose, If I am doing it in Java, then what is `your element id` in your first line of code?

Comment: you need to inspect your screen to find the automation Id. For inspecting element you can either use **uiautomatorviewer** or **Appium Desktop Inspector**. The element id will be the **string** value. If your dev team have use **content-description** you can use `@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "some value")`

Comment: If id is present for the element, you can use `@AndroidFindBy(id="some value")`. Some value is same as the value which you are using as `driver.FindElementById("some value"); `